# How to print the contents of an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I use the following code to print information of all persons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt = "";
var person = [{fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25},
              {fname:"Hasan", lname:"Doe", age:26}]; 
var x;
for (x in person) {
  txt += person[x] + " ";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the result is:

> [object Object] [object Object]

Why does this happen?

Comment: `txt += JSON.stringify( person[x] );`

Comment: @azad: didn't work

Comment: try this  txt += person[x].fname + " ";

Comment: Hello @user3486308 this is something you need to do, you have to push elements of your second array in txt array : 
`for (x in person) {
    txt.push(person[x]);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(txt);
`